# Login customer using customer id in magento

Tags: magento, authentication

I would like to login a customer using his/her customer_id.

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

Try this code :

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->loginById($customer_id);
```